# can the same asynctask can be called several times

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Can i call the same asynctask depending on some conditions?

for example:

```
switch(item)
{
  case 1:
    dataCommunicator.execute();
    break;
  case 2:
    dataComminicator.exwcute();
   break;
   .
   .
   .
}

class dataCommunicatoe extends AsyncTask{
  .
  .
  .
  .
  . 
}
```

Comment: can i pass dataCommunicatoe.execute(device1); and in the asyncTask in doInBackground can i put a switch statement?saying int item=params[0];and then switch(item){....}

Comment: switch statement with `String` is not possible. But with `int`, it's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a good approach is to pass an interface to a custom AsyncTask, so you can decide what to do when it reaches "OnPostExecute" and reuse the same custom AsyncTask for multiple fragments/activities.

Comment: can i have a switch statements inside my asynctask?

Comment: Yes, but you are not forced to use .execute() for that purpose. You can create a custom asyncTask with custom parameters and constructors, this is usually more usefull. Check this link http://www.androidsnippets.com/asyntask-in-android

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible:

You can call the same async task by passing parameters as below:

```
if (someLogicIsTrue)
    new AsyncTaskOperation().execute("FETCHUSER");
else
    new AsyncTaskOperation().execute("VALIDATECREDENTIALS");
```

Async Task should be:

```
private class AsyncTaskOperation extends AsyncTask <String, Void, Void>
{
        String paramObject = "";

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... paramsObj) {
        paramObject = paramsObj[0];

        if ("FETCHUSER".equals(paramObject))
        {
              // OPERATION FOR  FETCH USER
        }
        else if ("VALIDATECREDENTIALS".equals(paramObject))
       {
             // OPERATION FOR VALIDATE CREDENTIALS.
       }
       return null;
     }

}
```